# How can I return the number of pairs that do not satisfy the sorting condition from largest to smallest using merge sort?

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

I have a function `public static int countBaad(int[] hs)` that takes in an input array and I'm supposed to find how many numbers are smaller than the ones ahead of it.

For instance,

if `hs = [7,3,5,4,1]` the answer would be 2 because the pairs that violate the order are 3 and 5 and 3 and 4, since 3 is smaller than them and should've been ahead of them.

if `hs = [8,5,6,7,2,1]` the answer would be 3 because 5 is smaller than 6 and 7, giving us 2, and since 6 is also smaller than 7, we would get a total of 3 wrong pairs

Here is my current code using the merge sort approach:

```
    public static int countBaad(int[] hs){
        return mergeSort(hs, hs.length);
    }

    public static int mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return n;
        }
        int mid = n / 2;
        int[] l = new int[mid];
        int[] r = new int[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            l[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            r[i - mid] = a[i];
        }
        mergeSort(l, mid);
        mergeSort(r, n - mid);

        return merge(a, l, r, mid, n - mid);
    }
    public static int merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r, int left, int right) {
        int size = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
                a[k++] = l[i++];
                size++;
            }
            else {
                a[k++] = r[j++];
                size++;
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            a[k++] = l[i++];
            size++;
        }
        while (j < right) {
            a[k++] = r[j++];
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }
```

This code gives me the incorrect output after I put in arrays

`hs = [7,3,5,4,1]` returns 5

`hs = [8,5,6,7,2,1]` returns 6

What am I doing wrong here, can anyone please correct me?

Comment: Your method `mergeSort(int[] a, int n)` unconditionally calls itself 2 times. How would that method execution ever end and the return statement ever be reached?

Comment: A method that calls itself recursively needs some kind of base case where it stops calling itself and instead returns. Otherwise you'll just always have an infinite loop of a method calling itself until you get a StackOverflowError.

Comment: When you say you are getting wrong results, what *are* those results? Please post the code with which you are actually getting a result, because as @OHGODSPIDERS has already stated, your code results in `StackOverflowError`. As it is you are missing a loop terminating condition.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS my apologies, I didn't copy the full code

Comment: @ThomasTimbul my apologies, I have edited it. I didn't fully copy my code from my IDE

Answer (score 0):

What your code is currently doing is attempting a sort and then simply returning the size of the sorted array (big surprise, given the aptly named `size` variable).

Basically you are sorting in descending order and your specification calls for the result to be how many numbers were smaller than those appearing later in the array.
However, in `merge` you are actually adding to `size` regardless of their values.

Then, you're only returning the 'size' result of the final merge, not that of the sorting steps required inbetween.

And finally, perhaps the elephant in the room, is that you're performing a (unnecessary) sort as a side effect, but ignoring it completely.

**Long story short**, the code is too complicated and error prone for what it is supposed to do.

Here's a simple double for loop that achieves the desired outcome:

```
    public static int countBaad(int[] hs){
        
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < hs.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < hs.length; j++) {
                //compare the i'th position with all subsequent positions
                int current = hs[i];
                int other = hs[j];
                if(current < other) {
                    System.out.println("Found bad number pair: ("+current+","+other+")");
                    count++;
                }
            }
            
        }
        return count;
    }

System.out.println(countBaad(new int[]{7,3,5,4,1}));
//prints:
//Found bad number pair: (3,5)
//Found bad number pair: (3,4)
//2
System.out.println(countBaad(new int[]{8,5,6,7,2,1}));
//prints:
//Found bad number pair: (5,6)
//Found bad number pair: (5,7)
//Found bad number pair: (6,7)
//3
```

This is much more succinct and free from side effects.

**Edit:**

Fixing the mergeSort code, with extra sysout logging to illustrate the algorithm:

```
    public static int mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
        if(n==1) {
            //No sorting required, so the result should be 0.
            return 0;
        }
        int mid = n / 2;
        
        int[] l = new int[mid];
        int[] r = new int[n - mid];
        
        //'splitting the array' loops are just arraycopy, so
        // should use the native implementation:
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, l, 0, mid);
        if(n - mid >= 0) System.arraycopy(a, mid, r, 0, n - mid);
        
        //add the results from all merges, not just the last one
        int result = 0;
        result += mergeSort(l, mid);
        result += mergeSort(r, n - mid);
        result += merge(a, l, r); //there is no need to pass in the array lengths
        return result;
    }
    public static int merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r) {
        System.out.println("Merging "+Arrays.toString(l)+" and "+Arrays.toString(r));
        int size = 0;
        int lIdx = 0, rIdx = 0, aIdx = 0;
        while (lIdx < l.length && rIdx < r.length) {
            if (l[lIdx] >= r[rIdx]) {
                a[aIdx++] = l[lIdx++];
                //size++; //no: left was already bigger than right
            }
            else {
                //take from the right.
                //This number is bigger than all the numbers remaining on the left.
                for(int tempIdx = lIdx;tempIdx<l.length;tempIdx++) {
                    //this loop is for illustration only
                    System.out.println("  Found bad pair: (" + l[tempIdx] + "," + r[rIdx] + ")");
                }
                size+=l.length-lIdx;
                a[aIdx++] = r[rIdx++];
            }
        }
        
        //while (lIdx < left) { //NOTE that you had this condition incorrectly reversed resulting in bad merge
        //  a[aIdx++] = l[lIdx++];
        //  size++; //no, no comparisons are taking place here
        //}
        //while (rIdx < right) { //NOTE that you had this condition incorrectly reversed, resulting in bad merge
        //  a[aIdx++] = r[rIdx++];
        //  size++; //no, no comparisons are taking place here
        //}
        
        //we can also replace the above two loops with arraycopy
        // which will perform better on large arrays
        if(lIdx < left) {
            System.arraycopy(l, lIdx, a, aIdx, l.length-lIdx);
        }
        if(rIdx < right) {
            System.arraycopy(r, rIdx, a, aIdx, r.length-rIdx);
        }
        
        return size;
    }
```

Since you value performance, you should use System.arraycopy where possible. I have also renamed the loop variables to make the code easier to understand.

```
System.out.println(countBaad(new int[]{7,3,5,4,1}));
//prints:
//Merging [7] and [3]
//Merging [4] and [1]
//Merging [5] and [4, 1]
//Merging [7, 3] and [5, 4, 1]
//  Found bad pair: (3,5)
//  Found bad pair: (3,4)
//2
System.out.println(countBaad(new int[]{8,5,6,7,2,1}));
//prints:
//Merging [5] and [6]
//  Found bad pair: (5,6)
//Merging [8] and [6, 5]
//Merging [2] and [1]
//Merging [7] and [2, 1]
//Merging [8, 6, 5] and [7, 2, 1]
//  Found bad pair: (6,7)
//  Found bad pair: (5,7)
//3
```

**Edit #2**

To remove the side effects (sort) from this method, the input array can be copied, for example with a simple call to `Arrays.copyOf(hs, hs.length);` and passing in the result instead of the original.

Comment: The reason I did my code that way is due to the fact that I want the running time to be O(n log n), and the one that you have provided are o(n^2)

Comment: is there any way you could change ur code to get a running time of O(n log n)?

Comment: I've learnt that merge sort uses O (n log n ) time complexity, which is why I used it.  If you could edit your code to get a O( n log n) time complexity, then it would be really helpful, thank you

Comment: Added fixed mergeSort code as requested. Multiple small errors were adding up...